# Uploads within NancyFX hang on upload

Tags: c#, .net, azure-storage, nancy, azure-storage-files

nuget package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File 9.4.2 uploads files somewhere < 26MB just fine, and silently hangs indefinitely when uploading files > 26MB.

Project is targeting .NET (Desktop) Framework 4.7.2.

***** Update *****
This problem occurs when attempting a large-ish file upload, using various clients, and to various cloud services (I've experienced the same problem uploading to S3), but only within the context of a NancyFx web application.  Same problem occurs locally as when deployed to an Azure App Service, so it is almost certainly unrelated to my local dev configuration.

To be clear, the uploads hang when attempting an upload **within** a NancyFx application; I am not uploading **to** a NancyFx application.

For now, my solution is to just don't do the file upload from within Nancy, but I'll leave this question open in case anyone has an interest in a technical solution to the problem that still exists.

***** End Update *****

And to be clear, file uploads

Attempted usage is as follows:

```
public void UploadFileFromFile(string azureFileName, string localFileName)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(SafeConfig.AzureFileStorageMaterialConnectionString);
    CloudFileClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    CloudFileShare share = client.GetShareReference(SafeConfig.AzureFileStorageMaterialShareName);
    CloudFileDirectory dir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
    CloudFile fileReference = dir.GetFileReference(azureFileName);
    fileReference.UploadFromFile(localFileName);
}
```

Worth noting, the client hangs just the same when I use the `fileReference.UploadFromByteArray()` method, and also hangs the same when I try using the various *Async alternatives as well.

When I try use the method `fileReference.UploadFromStream()`, I get an exception "*Object is not in a usable state*," which I do not consider to be a particularly actionable exception message.  This is my preferred method to use for uploading, but the different error experience might make it a separate question.

Comment: You can actually utilize CloudBlockBlob.Upload file for uploading bigger file and also it can be tuned for special cases like slow internet. Sometime upload operation gets failed because of slow internet connectivity.. Here is a very nice article which explain the usage of UploadFIle and tune by splitting a bigger file into smaller one. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same package and same code as yours, everything is fine and file size more than 26M can be uploaded. Can you try to restart your visual studio and try again?

My code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
using System;

namespace MyConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            string azureFileName = "1.zip";
            string localFileName = @"D:\1.zip";

            Console.WriteLine("start upload..");

            p.UploadFileFromFile(azureFileName, localFileName);

            Console.WriteLine("completed**");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void UploadFileFromFile(string azureFileName, string localFileName)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("xxxx");
            CloudFileClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare share = client.GetShareReference("testfolder");
            CloudFileDirectory dir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            CloudFile fileReference = dir.GetFileReference(azureFileName);
            Console.WriteLine("going to upload");
            fileReference.UploadFromFile(localFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

The file can be uploaded:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for putting together this example, Ivan.  I've found that many file uploads to many cloud services hang, but only within the context of a NancyFx web application, so I have updated the question accordingly, and have transitioned to uploading files from within almost any other execution context, and so far, all other execution contexts (Console App, Azure Web Job, even an Xunit integration test) seem to work fine.